# Envío request en QT4.8 y recibo respuesta vacía

Tags: c++, post, qt, requests

Tengo que realizar una petición `POST` hacia un servidor al que estoy conectado por un túnel. Al realizar la petición por comando `CURL` recibo el `json` esperado en la consola. Ahora intento pasarlo a QT, que es lo que se necesita, y no consigo que funcione. El código corre, pero al hacer debug la respuesta siempre está vacía y el código de error es 0. He mirado tanto tutoriales como preguntas similares en stackoverflow y no he conseguido solucionarlo. Este es mi código:

```
QString NetManager::CheckSite(QString url)
{
    QNetworkRequest req;
    QUrl myUrl = QUrl("http://UNAURL:8080/path/al/recurso");

    req.setUrl(myUrl);
    req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    QUrl postData;
    postData.addQueryItem("client_id", "ID");
    postData.addQueryItem("username", "admin");
    postData.addQueryItem("password", "pass");
    postData.addQueryItem("grant_type", "password");

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    //do connection with needed signal and slot which we alredy wrote
    //QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(req,postData.encodedQuery());
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(req,postData.encodedQuery());

    QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();
    QString str = QString::fromUtf8(bytes.data(), bytes.size());
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

    return str;

}
```

**Edito** para agregar el código de ReplyFinished

```
void NetManager::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();
    QString str = QString::fromUtf8(bytes.data(), bytes.size());
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    std::cout << "State: "+statusCode;

}
```

Comment: `QNetworkReply` tiene dos métodos: `isRunning` y `isFinished`... has probado a verificar el estado de estos flags antes de leer la respuesta?

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer, y ambos son correctos, es decir, ha acabado y no está corriendo.

Comment: He estado haciendo más pruebas y parece que, efectivamente, a veces `QNetworkReply` no acaba. ¿Como puedo prevenir este comportamiento. Pensaba que en el connect se gestionaba justamente este aspecto (soy muy nuevo usando las capacidades de red de QT).

Comment: Conectaste la señal `finished` a la función `replyFinished`. Se llamará cuando llegue la señal. Tienes que verificar la respuesta en esa función.

Comment: He agregado la función `ReplyFinished`. El problema es que de la respuesta necesito recuperar un token y no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo de momento.

Comment: Pero esa es otra pregunta diferente. Una cosa es que no recibas la respuesta y otra muy diferente que no sepas cómo procesar un json... ¿Cual es tu duda en este caso?

Comment: Mis disculpas, con el anterior comentario he podido liar la cosa. La duda es como conseguir que llegue la respuesta, dentro de la cual está el token que necesito. Entiendo que al ser una petición asíncrona, debo hacer algún tipo de espera porque, en este caso, sin el token de la respuesta no puedo hacer más peticiones.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he conseguido el respose con el token gracias a [ESTE](https://gist.github.com/vannell/16b8d6f4dc7e21fa0431) código de GitHub, modificándolo convenientemente para que realice una petición `POST` con los datos necesarios. Si alguien quiere que ponga mi versión simplemente que lo pida. Gracias a todos por la ayuda :).